# remastersys ubuntu and lack of space

Tags: linux

I have a CD with a Ubuntu version, and i need to burn it again to create a new version with a new script there but i cant create the new version, every time i try to save the image with a software called **Remastersys**, i get errors of "lack of space,  failed to write".

I tried , every directory with no success. i have  always the same error and i dont get the .ISO, the options i tried was : go to remastersys.conf and point the temporary directory to /tmp and to a usb on the machine to no success, the only option i see is either to install it and try to save after i have this exact version running on the cd on the Disk or create all from scratch again.

Is  it possible to install this exact image or save a image of this system a exact image of the system as it is running by the **CD** as  a **.ISO** ?

```
ss@ss:~$ df
df: «/root/.gvfs»: Permissão negada
Sist.fichs     1K-blocos   Ocup  Livres Uso% Montado em
/cow             2005388  70128 1935260   4% /
udev             1994968      4 1994964   1% /dev
tmpfs             802156    804  801352   1% /run
/dev/sr0          990570 990570       0 100% /cdrom
/dev/loop0        964608 964608       0 100% /rofs
tmpfs            2005388     24 2005364   1% /tmp
none                5120      0    5120   0% /run/lock
none             2005388     76 2005312   1% /run/shm
/dev/sdb1        3927936 559104 3368832  15% /media/USB1
/dev/sdc1        3929120 596704 3332416  16% /media/USB2
/dev/sdd1        7970812 286164 7684648   4% /media/USB3
ss@ss:~$ 


ss@ss:~$ mount
/cow on / type overlayfs (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
/dev/sr0 on /cdrom type iso9660 (ro,noatime)
/dev/loop0 on /rofs type squashfs (ro,noatime)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
gvfs-fuse-daemon on /home/sgs/.gvfs type fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=sgs)
/dev/sdb1 on /media/USB1 type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,uid=1000,gid=1000,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush,uhelper=udisks)
/dev/sdc1 on /media/USB2 type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,uid=1000,gid=1000,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush,uhelper=udisks)
/dev/sdd1 on /media/USB3 type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,uid=1000,gid=1000,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush,uhelper=udisks)
gvfs-fuse-daemon on /root/.gvfs type fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon (rw,nosuid,nodev)
ss@ss:~$ 


ss@ss:~$ cat /etc/remastersys.conf

#Remastersys Global Configuration File


# This is the temporary working directory and won't be included on the cd/dvd
WORKDIR="/tmp"


# Here you can add any other files or directories to be excluded from the live filesystem
# Separate each entry with a space
EXCLUDES=""


# Here you can change the livecd/dvd username
LIVEUSER="custom"


# Here you can change the name of the livecd/dvd label
LIVECDLABEL="Custom Live CD"


# Here you can change the name of the ISO file that is created
CUSTOMISO="custom-$1.iso"


# Here you can change the mksquashfs options
SQUASHFSOPTS="-no-recovery -always-use-fragments -b 1M -no-duplicates"


# Here you can prevent the Install icon from showing up on the desktop in backup mode. 0 - to not show 1 - to show 
BACKUPSHOWINSTALL="1"


# Here you can change the url for the usb-creator info
LIVECDURL="http://www.remastersys.com"
ss@ss:~$
```

Comment: It is unclear what exactly you're doing and what you've already tried. No space is no space, you have to write image _somewhere_

Comment: Still too cryptic. Have i got it right - you're booting from live CD and want to modify it? Where do you want to save resulting image to?

Comment: its not possible, i try to point the mounting of the iso on usb with 30Gb free and he  tells me that there is no space to create the temporary iso that is later gonna turn to the iso (the real  one on usb for example)

Comment: @keltar i want to save it to a USB device

Comment: Where are you trying to save resulting iso? (path). Where is your usb drive mounted? Do /tmp have enough space? (on live CD it is in RAM, so quite limited - check `df` command). Does usb drive mounted in read-write mode?

Comment: im affraid the ram is not enough but yes it is mounted in read and write mode.

Comment: Please add your remastersys.conf, `df` output, `mount` output and remastersys output to question. Things doesn't add up, it should be ok.

Comment: done, right now i edit the question to have the info you want @keltar

Comment: Don't see output of remastersys in your post. Anyway, try `WORKDIR="/media/USB3"`. `cd` to this directory before invoking remastersys. Also, not sure if it is required to work on vfat file system - try ext2 if it doesn't.

Comment: i did it tanks i format the usb to ext2 and it worked